# Is it possible to render fully-qualified domain name (instead of IP address) of node using Consul Template?

Tags: consul, consul-template, consul-kv

I am trying to template config for an application using Consul Template. I would like the address of a node, discoverable using Consul, to be of the form `metrics-server` (or `metrics-server.example.com` which I could then parse).

The below code is currently rendering an IP address, e.g `125.32.546.1`, not the fully-qualified domain name that I require.

```
{{ with node }}{{ .Node.Address }}{{ end }}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the domain name using Consul Template syntax and without using `.Node` and additional parsing?

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at the Consul source code (specifically [`structs.go`](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/agent/structs/structs.go)) and after some trial and error, I determined that

```
{{ with node }}{{ .Node.Node }}{{ end }}
```

would render

```
metrics-server.example.com
```

I then used some Golang [template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) logic to split on `.` and get the first element of the resultant slice. That is,

```
{{ with node }}{{ index (split "." .Node.Node) 0 }}{{ end }}
```

renders

```
metrics-server
```